# Join and count distinct values between 2 dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, distinct, date-range

I have a left table:

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
  code int
, max  date
, min  date
);
```

And a right table with user activity (one line per user per day):

```
CREATE TABLE activity (
  date   date
, "user" text
);
```

Sample data:

Table `tab` (with the added column I am trying to compute):

```
Code  Min          Max            (Expected output)
201   2019-1-8    2019-1-10           3
202   2019-1-8    2019-1-11           3
203   2019-1-11   2019-1-12           2
```

Table `activity`:

```
Date              User
2019-1-8         ABCD001
2019-1-8         ABCD002
2019-1-9         ABCD001
2019-1-9         ABCD003
2019-1-10        ABCD001
2019-1-11        ABCD002
2019-1-12        ABCD003
```

I want as output the columns of `tab`, extended with the count of distinct users `activity` within that date range

So I need to join on the date range between `min` and `max` somehow.

Trial 1:

```
select code, min, max, count(b.distinct user)
from tab a
left join activity b on b.date between a.min and a.max
group by 1,2,3
```

Trial 2:

```
select code, min, max, count(b.distinct user)
from tab a
left join activity b on b.date <= a.min and b.date >=a.max and b.date = a.min
group by 1,2,3
```

I ran different versions of the above code, but it either takes ages to run or fails.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a `LEFT JOIN LATERAL`:

```
SELECT a.code, a.min, a.max, b.ct
FROM   tab a
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT count(DISTINCT b."user") AS ct
   FROM   activity b
   WHERE  b.date BETWEEN a.min AND a.max
   ) b ON true;
```

A query like this can be expensive if ranges are not trivially small. Each row on the left involves a range of rows on the right. A `DISTINCT` count is expensive on top of it, for big ranges. But this should be the fastest query possible.

Support it with an **index** on `activity(date, "user")`. Only add the 2nd index column if you get index-only scans out of it.

`user` is a [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html), btw. Don't use it as identifier.
And I wouldn't use `date`, `min` or `max` either. Names of basic data types and functions as identifiers can lead to confusing errors.

Related:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Comment: Thank you! I will run it and update the thread. Appreciate the code edit.  I will learn for the future